# Expected primary expression before '.'

Tags: c++, class

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class square {

public:
    double length, width;
    
    square(double length, double width);
    square();
    
    ~square();
    
    double perimeter();
};

double square::perimeter() {
return 2*square.length + 2*square.width;
}

int main() {

square sq(4.0, 4.0);

cout << sq.perimeter() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to write a simple class program. I am getting the error

```
in member function 'double square::perimeter()';
.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

Does this mean I have to use `2*square::length + 2*square::width`?

Comment: Why would a square have a different `length` and `width`? You could just use `side`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`square` is a *type*, not an object; instead of

```
return 2*square.length + 2*square.width;
```

do

```
return 2*length + 2*width;
```

(which is implicitly the same as:

```
return 2*this->length + 2*this->width;
```

which you may, or <sup><sup>please</sup></sup> may not, prefer for clarity).

`2*square::length + 2*square::width` would be valid syntax if `length` and `width` were

- *static* members of `square`, or
- members of some base class `square`, or
- objects in some namespace `square`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the accurate form would be:

```
return 2*square::length + 2*square::width;
```

since `square` is a type, not an object.

In this context, it's the same as:

```
return 2*this->square::length + 2*this->square::width;
```

However, since it's the *same* object and the *same* type, you can just write:

```
return 2*this->length + 2*this->width;
```

or, most simply:

```
return 2*length + 2*width;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
double square::perimeter() {
    return 2 * length + 2 * width;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
double square::perimeter() {
    return 2*square.length + 2*square.width;
}
```

You need to say `square::perimeter()` because you are defining a method of the square class itself. It may seem like you want to define it on a specific object, but you want it to be available to all instances of square, so you need to define it on a specific one.

The instance variables `length` and `width` on the other hand, pertain to a specific instance of a class and NOT the entire class itself (otherwise you would declare them as `static`). This means that you can just refer to them directly instead of going through the class itself, and the compiler will know what variables you're talking about. This is because `width` and `length` are defined in the same scope as the method, so you don't need to give it special directions with `::` to tell it where to find what its looking for. Hence:

```
double square::perimeter() {
    return 2 * length + 2 * width; //will refer to the instance variables automatically
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to access instance variables, just name them:

```
double square::perimeter() {
  return 2*length + 2*width;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double square::perimeter() {
return 2*square.length + 2*square.width;
}
```

what is the `square` in this function? square is a class. you use the `.` operator to acces members from objects. like `sq.somefun();`

so you perimeter function should be:

```
 double square::perimeter() {
    return (2*(length + width));
    }
```

*But isnt the length and width of square equal?*